# Openlayers a.setMap is not a function when add wmsGetFeatureInfo

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers, wms, geoext

When i'm building popup using WMSGetFeratureInfo, my popup map working. but when i add some hover popup using WMSGetFeratureInfo.  my map sending error massage "a.setMap is not a function".

i think it might be related to library in openlayers but I am no expert so any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Here's my code

```js
info = {click: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({url : 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web-gis/wms',
    title : 'Identify features by clicking',
    queryVisible : true,
    eventListeners : {
    getfeatureinfo : function(event) {
    //deletePopUp();
    popup = new     OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popInfo", map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy), null, event.text, null, true);
    map.addPopup(popup);}}
            }),
            hover: "test"
   new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web-gis/wms',
    title : 'Identify features by clicking',
    queryVisible : true,
    hover : true,
    eventListeners : {
    getfeatureinfo : function(event) {
    //deletePopUp();
    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popInfo", map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy), null, event.text, null, true);
    map.addPopup(popup);
    }}
            })
            };
            map.addControl(info.hover);
            info.hover.activate();
```